# верстка двух блоков css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при размещении 2 блоков через li они просто исчезают, как исправить?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(145.59deg, #29FF8C -19.48%, #3AC1A8 22.2%, #7000FF 133.44%, #7ECAE2 137.8%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.nav-btn {
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-right: 110px;
}

.nav-btn:hover,
.nav-btn:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: #778ed5;
}

.enter {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  margin-left: 410px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.enter:hover,
.enter:active {
  color: #32E19B;
}

.reg_btn {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #29FF8C;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(41, 255, 140, 0.4);
}

.reg_btn:hover,
.reg_btn:active {
  background: #23C66E;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(41, 255, 140, 0.4);
}

.main-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 88%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.block-with-img-and-title {
  display: block;
  width: 32%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
}

.main-block {
  display: flex;
}

.a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-block {
  display: block;
  width: 68%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <li>
    <div class="nav-btn">рецепты</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-btn">Избранные</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-btn">Создать</div>
  </li>
  <li><a class="enter" href="#">рецепты</a></li>
  <li><button class='reg_btn'>Регистрация</button></li>
</div>
<div class="main-block">
  <li class="a">
    <div class="block-with-img-and-title"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="a">
    <div class="text-block"></div>
  </li>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пропиши что то внутрь и они появятся

```
<div class = "main-block">
    <li class = "a"><div class = "block-with-img-and-title">123</div></li>
    <li class = "a"><div class = "text-block">123</div></li>
</div>
```

Comment: а, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, не особо понял что вам нужно, так что сделал как на картинке

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(145.59deg, #29FF8C -19.48%, #3AC1A8 22.2%, #7000FF 133.44%, #7ECAE2 137.8%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.nav-btn {
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-right: 110px;
}

.nav-btn:hover,
.nav-btn:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: #778ed5;
}

.enter {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  margin-left: 410px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.enter:hover,
.enter:active {
  color: #32E19B;
}

.reg_btn {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #29FF8C;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(41, 255, 140, 0.4);
}

.reg_btn:hover,
.reg_btn:active {
  background: #23C66E;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(41, 255, 140, 0.4);
}

.main-block {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 88%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.block-with-img-and-title {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.text-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 70vw;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  font: normal 32px Oswald;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
}

h4 {
  font: normal 32px Oswald;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  height: 650px;
  width: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(145.59deg, #7ECAE2 -19.48%, #7000FF 22.2%, #3AC1A8 133.44%, #29FF8C 137.8%);
  top: 0;
  right: -40px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <li>
    <div class="nav-btn">Рецепты</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-btn">Избранные</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="nav-btn">Создать</div>
  </li>
  <li><a class="enter" href="#">Рецепты</a></li>
  <li><button class='reg_btn'>Регистрация</button></li>
</div>
<div class="main-block">
  <li class="a">
    <div class="block-with-img-and-title">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <h4>Жареная курица</h4>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </li>
  <li class="a">
    <div class="text-block">Основное</div>
  </li>
</div>
```